# Require to Send a formatted HTML Email via Database Mail in Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-mail

I need to send an e-mail from SQL Server in the below format, as requested by the client:

> Dear colleague,
>
> See attached file with your current list of high priority ticket notifications.
>
> Following tickets are listed:
>
> * High priority tickets: last article time is at least 7 calendar days in the past.
> * Very high priority tickets: last article is at least 3 calendar days in the past.
>
> Please check if the priority of these tickets is still correct.
> If so, don’t forget to focus on them.
>
> Thanks in advance for reserving some time to work on them.

As of now I have been using the below format to send short messages:

```
Declare @BODY VARCHAR(50)
declare @id  varchar
declare @email_id varchar(50)
DECLARE emailCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id, email_id FROM email_address
OPEN emailCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM emailCursor INTO @id, @email_id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @BODY = 'The following ticket'  +  @id  + 'is open' 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = @email_id,
        @profile_name='Currency Rate Notifier',
        @subject = 'Open tickets',
        @body = @BODY
    FETCH NEXT FROM emailCursor INTO @id, @email_id
END
CLOSE emailCursor
DEALLOCATE emailCursor
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would definitely recommend reading the manual on `sp_send_dbmail` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190307.aspx

Comment: @Mark- I just missed a small logic.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

When calling `sp_send_dbmail`, you can set `@body_format='HTML'` and place the HTML source code in the `@body` parameter.

Important: I'm not sure if there will be a plain-text version of your message for recipients that can't or won't read HTML formatted e-mail.

Like Mark says, you should check the [documentation for sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190307.aspx) for more information. Also, if you want the challenge, you could use the `FOR XML` construct in a `SELECT` statement to generate an XML document where the elements are named and arranged like HTML tags.